# Scheduled Python tasks in Heroku Application

Tags: python, flask, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I'm hosting a Flask application in Heroku(free) which acts as an API and reads from an SQLite database file.

The way the project ran on my computer, I had scheduled Python scripts which would run every night and append new data to my SQLite database, which would then in turn be able to be used by my Flask Application.

However, hosted on Heroku, I don't think I will be able to run my Flask application and a python script 24/7. I know there is an alternate solution APScheduler on Flask, which would carry out tasks in Python functions in the Flask application. However, according to Heroku's free use guidelines, if there is no traffic to my page in 30 minutes, the application will "sleep." I'm assuming that means scheduled tasks will no longer work once the application is asleep, which defeats the purpose of using APScheduler.

Are there any alternatives I could use to go about this?